# Critical points for a function of $n$ variables.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Suppose we have a function defined as;
$$f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$$
And we wish to determine and classify the critical points of this solid. Or in other words, we want to determine the points $x,y,z$ such that;
$$\nabla f(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$$
From this, it can easily be seen that the critical point occurs at $(0,0,0)$. However, I don't know how to classify such a critical point in the case of a function of 3 variables. Namely, I have considered the $3\times 3$ Hessian matrix;
$$H= \begin{pmatrix}f_{xx} & f_{xy} & f_{xz} \\ f_{yx} & f_{yy} & f_{yz} \\ f_{zx} & f_{zy} & f_{zz}\end{pmatrix}$$
From this, I then determined the eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix and found them to all be positive. I then checked that the product of the eigenvalues determined equaled $\det{(H)}$. So this means that I have done this computation correctly. Since all the eigenvalues were found to be all positive, this then corresponds to a minimum critical point. Is the way that I have answered this questions correct?

Comment: In this case, the eigenvalues of $H$ can be found by inspection, but in practice other tests for positive-definiteness are usually easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you've applied the second derivative test correctly. The Hessian is symmetric (as it is in almost every problem), and by showing that the eigenvalues are all positive, you have shown the matrix to be positive-definite. By the second derivative test, the critical point $(0, 0, 0)$ is a local minimum.

You also could have observed that $f(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \ge 0 + 0 + 0 = f(0, 0, 0)$, since $x^2, y^2, z^2 \ge 0$, and concluded that $(0, 0, 0)$ is a global (and hence local) minimiser.